# Can GNU Make add a prefix to recipe echo lines?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make, output

I am using GNU Make and would like it to add a prefix to each recipe command as it's echoed. For example, given this makefile:

```
foo:
    echo bar
    echo baz
```

Actual behavior:

```
$ make -B foo
echo bar
bar
echo baz
baz
```

Desired behavior:

```
$ make -B foo
+ echo bar
bar
+ echo baz
baz
```

(In this case, `+` is the prefix.)

It would be nice if I could configure what the prefix is, but that's not essential.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is to change the `SHELL` make variable. In this case, running the shell with the `-x` parameter should do the trick. Something like

```
$ make SHELL:='bash -x'
```

Or even

```
$ make .SHELLFLAGS:='-x -c'
```

in this case. For more sophisticated output a quick shell script fits the bill:

```
$ cat script
#!/bin/bash
echo "EXECUTING [$*]"
$*
```

followed by

```
$ make SHELL:=./script .SHELLFLAGS:=
```

Comment: This then requires prefixing each recipe in the makefile with `@` (or using `.SILENT`), to prevent Make from printing the command too?

Comment: @Reid Well I suppose you use can also just use the `-s` make parameter.

Answer (score 3):

This isn't something Make does very naturally. I don't think you can do better than a horrible kludge:

```
define trick
    @echo + $(1)
    @$(1)
endef

foo:
    $(call trick, echo bar)
    $(call trick, echo baz)
```